# What does “万人迷” mean in “我要变成万人迷”?

Tags: translation

What does “万人迷” mean in “我要变成万人迷”? I heard this in a song and I have no idea how to translate/understand it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

万人迷 is a noun literally means "The one who has a great many people crazy about"

"万人迷" mainly describes "人氣偶像"(popular idol), but any popular person could be called one, especially the ones who are popular among the opposite sex

You can translate 万人迷 as "**偶像**" (**idol**)

*Taylor Swift who has millions of fans is a good example of 万人迷*

Answer (score 1):

**迷** - fan; **crazy about**; enthuses

- “万人迷” - "a million people crazy about" = an idol
- 我要变成万人迷 - I ought to become an idol (with a million fans).

Answer (score 1):

万人 - 10,000 persons
迷 - bedazzled, charmed, fawned over

万人迷 - somebody with many fans